# How to customize a date picker

Tags: dart, flutter

I’m using the `showDatePicker()` method to display a date picker in my flutter application. How do I customize the colors of the date picker?

Here is my theme's code:

```
class CustomTheme extends Theme {
  /*
   * Colors:
   *    Primary Blue: #335C81 (51, 92, 129)
   *    Light Blue:   #74B3CE (116, 179, 206)
   *    Yellow:       #FCA311 (252, 163, 17)
   *    Red:          #E15554 (255, 85, 84)
   *    Green:        #3BB273 (59, 178, 115)
   */

  static int _fullAlpha = 255;
  static Color blueDark =  new Color.fromARGB(_fullAlpha, 51, 92, 129);
  static Color blueLight = new Color.fromARGB(_fullAlpha, 116, 179, 206);
  static Color yellow =    new Color.fromARGB(_fullAlpha, 252, 163, 17);
  static Color red =       new Color.fromARGB(_fullAlpha, 255, 85, 84);
  static Color green =     new Color.fromARGB(_fullAlpha, 59, 178, 115);

  static Color activeIconColor = yellow;


  CustomTheme(Widget child): super(
    child: child,
    data: new ThemeData(
      primaryColor: blueDark,
      accentColor: yellow,
      cardColor: blueLight,
      backgroundColor: blueDark,
      highlightColor: red,
      splashColor: green
    )
  );
}
```

Here is my code for wrapping the page in the theme:

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    [...]
    return new CustomTheme(
      new Scaffold(
        [...]
      )
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I assume that you want to customize the date picker *differently* from your main theme. Normally, date picker follow your main theme.

If so, wrap the button that triggers the action in a `Builder` inside a `Theme`. For example, here's a FAB that pops up an orange date picker (in a light material app theme), inheriting the rest from the main theme.

```
  floatingActionButton: new Theme(
    data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.amber,
        ),
    child: new Builder(
      builder: (context) => new FloatingActionButton(
            child: new Icon(Icons.date_range),
            onPressed: () => showDatePicker(
                  context: context,
                  initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
                  firstDate:
                      new DateTime.now().subtract(new Duration(days: 30)),
                  lastDate: new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 30)),
                ),
          ),
    ),
  ),
```

Check the source code of date_picker.dart to see which parts of the Theme affect different aspects of the date picker.

If you just want the picker to follow the main theme, here's a working example

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class PickerThemeDemo extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: const Text('Picker theme demo')),
      body: new Container(),
      floatingActionButton: new FloatingActionButton(
        child: new Icon(Icons.date_range),
        onPressed: () => showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              initialDate: new DateTime.now(),
              firstDate: new DateTime.now().subtract(new Duration(days: 30)),
              lastDate: new DateTime.now().add(new Duration(days: 30)),
            ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Color hexToColor(int rgb) => new Color(0xFF000000 + rgb);

class CustomTheme extends Theme {
  //Primary Blue: #335C81 (51, 92, 129)
  //Light Blue:   #74B3CE (116, 179, 206)
  //Yellow:       #FCA311 (252, 163, 17)
  //Red:          #E15554 (255, 85, 84)
  //Green:        #3BB273 (59, 178, 115)

  static Color blueDark = hexToColor(0x335C81);
  static Color blueLight = hexToColor(0x74B3CE);
  static Color yellow = hexToColor(0xFCA311);
  static Color red = hexToColor(0xE15554);
  static Color green = hexToColor(0x3BB273);

  CustomTheme(Widget child)
      : super(
          child: child,
          data: new ThemeData(
            primaryColor: blueDark,
            accentColor: yellow,
            cardColor: blueLight,
            backgroundColor: blueDark,
            highlightColor: red,
            splashColor: green,
          ),
        );
}

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      home: new CustomTheme(new PickerThemeDemo()),
    ),
  );
}
```

If you want to apply the theme to the whole app, it can be added most concisely (without the need for the CustomTheme class) to the Material app:

```
Color hexToColor(int rgb) => new Color(0xFF000000 + rgb);

void main() {
  runApp(
    new MaterialApp(
      theme: new ThemeData(
        brightness: Brightness.light,
        primaryColor: hexToColor(0x335C81),
        accentColor: hexToColor(0xFCA311),
        splashColor: hexToColor(0x3BB273),
      ),
      home: new PickerThemeDemo(),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: I would like the date picker to follow the main theme, which I customized. The entire page is wrapped in the theme, but it's not rolling over to the date picker for some reason.

Comment: That works for me. I've got italic text on a lurid background with a vivid splash on OK and Cancel. What's not working for you?

Comment: I'm wrapping the entire page in the custom theme, in which I set the primary color. The date picker is shown when the user taps on a `ListTile`. I'll update the question with my theme's code.

Comment: If I wrap my app in your custom theme, my date picker has: a dark blue banner, today's date, the selected date, OK and CANCEL in yellow, and OK and CANCEL splash green when clicked. Is this different from what you see?

Comment: Yea, I just see a date picker with the default theme

Comment: Just updated my question with my code for wrapping the page in the theme.

Comment: See the edited answer, or insert a Builder above your Scaffold, like this:   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new CustomTheme(
      new Builder(
        builder: (context) => new Scaffold(

Comment: I applied the theme to the entire app like you suggested, and it fixed the issue. Thanks!

Comment: how we can change theme of flat buttons appear at dialog ? I have tried a lot of ways but could not do that.

Comment: Thank you very much ✌, this was very helpful for me.

Answer (score 101):

**Flutter 2.0.2**

```
    showDatePicker(
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.yellow, // header background color
              onPrimary: Colors.black, // header text color
              onSurface: Colors.green, // body text color
            ),
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                foregroundColor: Colors.red, // button text color
              ),
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
  },
);
```

[image]

Comment: Shoutout for the `Theme.of(context)` as well, instead of just coding for one of the themes. Thanks!

Comment: How about the size of the days (green text)? How can I change those?

Comment: Amazing! Just what I needed for the TextButton color. Thanks!

Comment: @Kherel  how do i change circle color of selected date. by using your code it same as header color but i want different from header color

Answer (score 84):

The above answers are working except for the Ok/Cancel buttons. Just adding this in case somebody needs help on customizing it. It is a combination of colorScheme and buttonTheme.

```
showTimePicker(
  context: context,
  initialTime: TimeOfDay(hour: hour, minute: minute),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          primaryColor: const Color(0xFF8CE7F1),
          accentColor: const Color(0xFF8CE7F1),
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: const Color(0xFF8CE7F1)),
          buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary
          ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 46):

Try this

```
showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          initialDate: DateTime.now(),
          firstDate: DateTime(1970),
          builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
            return Theme(
              data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.dark(
                    primary: Colors.deepPurple,
                    onPrimary: Colors.white,
                    surface: Colors.pink,
                    onSurface: Colors.yellow,
                    ),
                dialogBackgroundColor:Colors.blue[900],
              ),
              child: child,
            );
          },
        );
```

Answer (score 25):

Just add `colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: const Color(0xFFed1e25)),` in *main.dart*
it's controls showDatePicker header color

to `theme: ThemeData()`

```
runApp(
    MaterialApp(
      ...
      theme: ThemeData(
        ...
        // CUSTOMIZE showDatePicker Colors
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: const Color(0xFFed1e25)),
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary),
        //
        ...
      ),
```

Answer (score 19):

There is **builder** parameter available with **showDatePicker()** method.

try this:

```
const MaterialColor buttonTextColor = const MaterialColor(
  0xFF4A5BF6,
  const <int, Color>{
    50: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    100: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    200: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    300: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    400: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    500: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    600: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    700: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    800: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
    900: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),
  },
);

showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(2018),
  lastDate: DateTime(2030),
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Theme(
        data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          primarySwatch: buttonTextColor,//OK/Cancel button text color
          primaryColor: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6),//Head background
          accentColor: const Color(0xFF4A5BF6)//selection color
          //dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,//Background color
           ),     
          child: child,
    );
  },
);
```

and you will get something like this:

[image]

Comment: I want to also add that if you want to change OK/CANCEL button text colors, you can use `primarySwatch`

Comment: @SinanBaymammadli thanks, my answer is updated with your suggestion.

Answer (score 7):

While I was playing around with the showDatePicker themeData, I found the following:

```
final DateTime now = DateTime.now();

final DateTime? selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: now,
    firstDate: DateTime(now.year, now.month, now.day),
    lastDate: DateTime(now.year + 2),
    builder: (context, child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.dark(
                onPrimary: Colors.black, // selected text color
                onSurface: Colors.amberAccent, // default text color
                primary: Colors.amberAccent // circle color
                ),
            dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.black54,
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    textStyle: const TextStyle(
                        color: Colors.amber,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                        fontSize: 12,
                        fontFamily: 'Quicksand'),
                    primary: Colors.amber, // color of button's letters
                    backgroundColor: Colors.black54, // Background color
                    shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        side: const BorderSide(
                            color: Colors.transparent,
                            width: 1,
                            style: BorderStyle.solid),
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(50))))),
        child: child!,
      );
    });
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you only want to change the theme data for the datePicker you need to wrap the widget responsible for showing the datePicker inside a Builder widget and ultimately wrap it all inside a Theme widget as shown below:

PS: But at the time I was writing this answer, the text color ("OK/CANCEL") was not accepted. It is a issue in the flutter framework.
[19623](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/19623) is the issue.

```
Widget dateOfBirth(String hintText){

    return Theme(
      data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
        primaryColor: Color(0xFFFF3661), //color of the main banner
        accentColor: Color(0xFFFF3661), //color of circle indicating the selected date
        buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
          textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.accent //color of the text in the button "OK/CANCEL"
        ),
      ),
      child: Builder(              // This widget is required for the theme to be applied
        builder: (context){
          return GestureDetector(
            onTap: () async {

              DateTime initialDate = DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 17,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day);

              final picked = await showDatePicker(
                context: context,
                initialDate: initialDate,
                firstDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 100,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day),
                lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year - 17,DateTime.now().month,DateTime.now().day),
              );

              if(picked != null && picked != dobSelected){
                setState(() {
                  dobSelected = picked; // dobSelected is variable to store the selected value
                });
              }

              return picked;
            },
            child: Padding(        //You can use any other widget here
              padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 40.0),
              child: Container(
                  height: 55,
                  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                  alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(3)),
                    color: Color(0xFFF2F2F2),
                  ),
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 13),
                  child: dobSelected == null?Text('Date Of Birth',style: TextStyle(color: widget.isLender?Color(0xFF8B8B8B):Color(0xFFB3B1B1),fontSize: 15),):Text(DateFormat('yyyy-MM-dd').format(dobSelected))
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
```

Output

### [image: custom datePicker flutter]

Hope this helps!!!

Answer (score 4):

```
**You can try this solution. I sloved my problem apply to this solution**

Future<DateTime> selectDate() async {
return await showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDatePickerMode: DatePickerMode.day,
  initialDate: selecteDate,
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData.light().copyWith(
          primaryColor: Colors.teal,
          accentColor: Colors.teal,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(primary: Colors.teal),
          buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
            textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary
          ),
      ),
      child: child,
    );
  },
  firstDate: widget.initialDate ?? DateTime.now().subtract(Duration(days: 
  30)),
  lastDate: widget.lastDate ?? DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 30)),
 );
}
```

Answer (score 3):

**Update from 2021**

Flutter 2.5.3

```
showDatePicker(
          context: context,
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Theme(
              data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
                  primary: Colors.blue,
                  onPrimary: Colors.white,
                  onSurface: Colors.black,
                ),
                textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                  style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                    primary: Colors.white,
                    backgroundColor: Colors.blue,
                    textStyle: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: 16,
                      fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              child: child!,
            );
          },
          helpText: 'Select Date',
          initialDate: _selectedDate,
          firstDate: DateTime.now(),
          lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 14)),
        ).then((pickedDate) {
          if (pickedDate == null) {
            return;
          }
          setState(() {
            _selectedDate = pickedDate;
            _date.value = TextEditingValue(
                text: DateFormat('dd-MM-yyyy').format(_selectedDate));
          });
        });
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 3):

This one worked for me

```
showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: DateTime.now(),
      firstDate: DateTime.now().subtract(const Duration(days: 365)),
      lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 365)),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(onPrimary: kWhite, onBackground: kWhite),
            datePickerTheme: const DatePickerThemeData(
              headerBackgroundColor: kPrimary,
              backgroundColor: kWhite,
              headerForegroundColor: kWhite,
              surfaceTintColor: kWhite,
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 1):

> If you still  face null safety problem in changing color in 2021 ..then here is the simeple solution

```
 Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget ?child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
          splashColor: Colors.black,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            button: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          accentColor: Colors.black,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Color(0xffffbc00),
              primaryVariant: Colors.black,
              secondaryVariant: Colors.black,
              onSecondary: Colors.black,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              surface: Colors.black,
              onSurface: Colors.black,
              secondary: Colors.black),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: child ??Text(""),
      );
    }
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(1960, 8),
    lastDate: DateTime.now());
if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
  setState(() {
    selectedDate = picked;
     

    String da = picked.day.toString() +
        "-" +
        picked.month.toString() +
        "-" +
        picked.year.toString();
    dateOfBirth.text = da;
  });}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was strugglin with that question too. Espacially to use it with dark and light mode. That's my solution with Flutter 3

```
showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: model.selectedDate,
      firstDate: DateTime.now(),
      lastDate: DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 2),
      currentDate: model.selectedDate,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme(
                brightness: theme.brightness, // uses the brightness of the user (Light or Dark)
                primary: theme.onPrimary, 
                onPrimary: theme.primary, 
                secondary: theme.primary, 
                onSecondary: theme.onPrimary, 
                error: theme.error,
                onError: theme.onError,
                background: theme.primary,
                onBackground: theme.onPrimary,
                surface: theme.primary,
                onSurface: theme.onPrimary),
            textTheme: Theme.of(context).primaryTextTheme, // sets the text color of Calender and manual date input
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    )
```

But there is happening a lot in the datePicker class itself and hot reload in flutter sometimes shows a different result. closing and reopening the date picker solves this issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you want a global setting for all your date pickers, then set the `ThemeData()` from your parent `MaterialApp()`

```
MaterialApp(
      ...
      theme: ThemeData(
      textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
      primary: const Color(0xFFFFFFFF),
      backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF8CE7F1),
      )),
      primarySwatch: createMaterialColor(const Color(0xFF8CE7F1)),
      textTheme:  Theme.of(context).textTheme.apply(
      bodyColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
      displayColor: const Color(0xFF000000),
      brightness: Brightness.light))
      ...
)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the Material 3 DP instead of falling back to M2, using above-mentioned methods, you can now specify the color using `dialogBackgroundColor`:

```
showDatePicker(
  ...
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white, // or any other bg color
      
      ),
      child: child!
    );
  },
);
```

Answer (score 1):

**Here the updated customisations like font, theme,textstyle,colors..etc for showDatePicker **

[image]

```
///This function used for showDatePicker and return the selected datetime
     static Future<DateTime?> datePicker(DateTime date, BuildContext context,
      {DateTime? firstDate,
      DateTime? lastDate,
      bool returnNull = false}) async {
    final DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
      initialDate: date,
      firstDate: firstDate ?? DateTime(1950, 1),
      lastDate: lastDate ?? DateTime(DateTime.now().year + 100),
      builder: (BuildContext context, Widget? child) {
        return Theme(
          data: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
            colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Colors.white,
              onPrimary: AppColors.bottomAppBarItemColor,
              onSurface: AppColors.bottomAppBarItemColor,
            ),
            textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
              style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                  primary: AppColors.bottomAppBarItemColor,
                  textStyle: AppTextStyle.style14wNormalBlueButton),
            ),
            textTheme: TextTheme(
                headlineLarge: AppTextStyle.style14wBlueButton,
                titleLarge:
                    AppTextStyle.style14wBlueButton, // Selected Date portrait
                labelSmall:
                    AppTextStyle.style14wBlueButton, // Title - SELECT DATE
                bodyLarge:
                    AppTextStyle.style14wBlueButton, // year gridbview picker
                titleMedium: AppTextStyle.style14wBlueButton, // input
                titleSmall:
                    AppTextStyle.style14wBlueButton, // month/year picker
                bodySmall: AppTextStyle.style14wBlueButton // days
                ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

Latest update for flutter 3.16+ and when useMaterial3 is set to true in the main them.

You can now adjust the date picker theme with its own custom date picker theme:

```
const DatePickerThemeData({
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.elevation,
    this.shadowColor,
    this.surfaceTintColor,
    this.shape,
    this.headerBackgroundColor,
    this.headerForegroundColor,
    this.headerHeadlineStyle,
    this.headerHelpStyle,
    this.weekdayStyle,
    this.dayStyle,
    this.dayForegroundColor,
    this.dayBackgroundColor,
    this.dayOverlayColor,
    this.todayForegroundColor,
    this.todayBackgroundColor,
    this.todayBorder,
    this.yearStyle,
    this.yearForegroundColor,
    this.yearBackgroundColor,
    this.yearOverlayColor,
    this.rangePickerBackgroundColor,
    this.rangePickerElevation,
    this.rangePickerShadowColor,
    this.rangePickerSurfaceTintColor,
    this.rangePickerShape,
    this.rangePickerHeaderBackgroundColor,
    this.rangePickerHeaderForegroundColor,
    this.rangePickerHeaderHeadlineStyle,
    this.rangePickerHeaderHelpStyle,
    this.rangeSelectionBackgroundColor,
    this.rangeSelectionOverlayColor,
    this.dividerColor,
    this.inputDecorationTheme,
    this.cancelButtonStyle,
    this.confirmButtonStyle,
  })
```

Have fun customizing!