# Change calendar button color for showDatePicker

Tags: flutter

I'm using showDatePicker to display a calendar. How do I change the button color and also the today's date background color

[image]

I've tried different colors setting in Theme Data. but the OK, Cancel & today's date still in blue

```
Theme(data: ThemeData(
      splashColor: Color(0xFFFE9BC0),
    )
    child: myWidget(),
);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to customize a date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321182/how-to-customize-a-date-picker)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What i did to change the color of the datePicker was:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red),
  child: myWidget(),
);
```

Setting an appropriate primarySwatch instead of splashColor will change all the appearance of the picker, this is because a swatch is like a palette of color.
Another thing you could do is set a primarySwatch with a MaterialColor similar to the one you want as main color and then customize the splash color or primary color like this:

```
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(primarySwatch: Colors.red, splashColor: Colors.green),
  child: myWidget(),
);
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks. changing the primarySwatch works. Now I need to come up with own custom swatch to fit the design colors. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

If you still face null safety problem in changing color in 2021 ..then here is the simeple solution

```
    Future<void> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
DateTime? picked = await showDatePicker(
      context: context,
    builder: (BuildContext context, Widget ?child) {
      return Theme(
        data: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
          splashColor: Colors.black,
          textTheme: TextTheme(
            subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
            button: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
          ),
          accentColor: Colors.black,
          colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
              primary: Color(0xffffbc00),
              primaryVariant: Colors.black,
              secondaryVariant: Colors.black,
              onSecondary: Colors.black,
              onPrimary: Colors.white,
              surface: Colors.black,
              onSurface: Colors.black,
              secondary: Colors.black),
              dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.white,
        ),
        child: child ??Text(""),
      );
    }
    initialDate: selectedDate,
    firstDate: DateTime(1960, 8),
    lastDate: DateTime.now());
if (picked != null && picked != selectedDate)
  setState(() {
    selectedDate = picked;
     

    String da = picked.day.toString() +
        "-" +
        picked.month.toString() +
        "-" +
        picked.year.toString();
    dateOfBirth.text = da;
  });}
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify primary color using the theme data's color scheme parameter.

```
 Future<DateTime?> showDateTimePicker(BuildContext ctx) async {
DateTime? selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget ?child) {
    var themeBloc = BlocProvider.of<ThemeBloc>(context);
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        splashColor:  Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          titleMedium: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          labelLarge: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        ),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
             primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
            onSecondary: themeBloc.state.themeMode == ThemeMode.dark.toString()
                ? Colors.white
                : Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            onPrimary: Colors.white,
            surface: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            onSurface: themeBloc.state.themeMode == ThemeMode.dark.toString()
                ? Colors.white
                : Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            secondary: Colors.white
        ),
        dialogBackgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      ),
      child: child ?? Text(""),
    );
  },
  context: ctx,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 60)),
);
return selectedDate;
```

}