# Size of the Date Picker in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am making an ipad in flutter. I have a date picker. But in landscape it is showing pretty big.

Is there any way to resize the date picker dialog[image]

Comment: I think this can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321182/how-to-customize-a-date-picker

Comment: It only modifies the theme. I was hoping to change the size as well

Comment: But it's using ThemData which contains size controls: width and height. As shown here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html.
At the moment I can't test that, but I think It may help.

Comment: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData/ThemeData.html . There is no height factor or any size factor. I think you mistook the container's height width as the size factors

Comment: Oh, yeah, sorry, that was container's height/width

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes, you can resize date picker dialog by Container(), SizedBox() etc. using it in builder, but only if you put it in something like Column(), for example:

```
return showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(Duration(days: 356)),
  builder: (context, child) {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0),
          child: Container(
            height: 450,
            width: 700,
            child: child,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  },
);
```

Comment: Interesting.  So I tried this exact same approach initially, but without the Column().  Ugh, that's a trick I guess I'll learn to keep in mind.  Those only work when in a parent that uses them?  That's pretty confusing until you realize it.

Answer (score 0):

With newer flutter version date picker is smaller and no longer takes up most of the screen

https://github.com/flutter/flutter/pull/50546