# How to resize text initialDate in showDatePicker

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to resize text size of `initialDate`. I find it's too big on cellphone sized devices.

```
Future<Null> _selectDate(BuildContext context) async {
    var formatter = new DateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
    final DateTime picked = await showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: selectedDate,
        firstDate: DateTime(1901, 1),
        lastDate: DateTime(2101),
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height / 1.2,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 1.5,
                child: child,
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
    if (picked != null)
      setState(() {
        selectedDate = picked;
        dateController.value = TextEditingValue(text: formatter.format(picked));
      });
  }
```

I borrowed this example code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/60037183/9554434.

Image of issue:
[image]

child:

[image]

Comment: what is child? is it Text widget?

Comment: Child would be the widget that displays the calendar where you choose the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution (for me) was that I was looking at the DatePicker and not the TextFormField in which the text was being held. It was a simple matter of:

```
TextFormField(
    style: TextStyle(
    fontSize: textSize,
),
```

This does not answer the question of how to resize initialDate, but it does solve the issue of the text being too big for the TextFormField.

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap child with [ThemeData](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/ThemeData-class.html) and [TextTheme property](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextTheme-class.html) and change font-size using [TextStyle](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/TextStyle-class.html) like this

```dart
ThemeData(
    textTheme: TextTheme(
        body1: TextStyle(fontSize: 10.0), // <-- here you can do your font smaller
        body2: TextStyle(fontSize: 8.0)
    )
)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue isn't the child. It's the initialDate.

Comment: Edited question with my actual code and images. Apologies for the unclarity.