# How to make a fullscreen Date picker in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I'm developing an app for a small Android device and I want to display a date picker in full screen, so that the buttons take up as much space as possible.

[image: Flutter Date Picker]

Already tried the answer of [Size of the Date Picker in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324174/size-of-the-date-picker-in-flutter)
as this:

```
showDatePicker(
        context: context,
        initialDate: DateTime.now(),
        firstDate: DateTime(2000),
        lastDate: DateTime(2025),
        builder: (context, child) {
          return Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              SizedBox(
                height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                child: child,
              ),
            ],
          );
        });
```

but that solution seems to work only to make it smaller.

Note: Also if you can recommend a date picker package that would be great!