# Is there a way to override the height/width of the date picker created by showDatePicker?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-datetime-picker

I am trying to increase the height and width of the date picker dialog shown when calling [showDatePicker()](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html). It currently appears quite small on tablets and I want to make it easier to interact with by increasing it's overall size. I have tried a few solutions which will be detailed below.

Example of how date picker dialog appears on tablet portrait, doesn't really make use of available space

[image]

First I tried following the accepted answer detailed on this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59324174/size-of-the-date-picker-in-flutter) which seemingly can change the height and of the date picker dialog but only up to a point (max width 328, max height 512) which isn't very useful when the size is still too small on tablet devices.

Next I dug into the [date picker source code](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/date_picker.dart) and found the private values which seems to control the overall size of the dialog. The main value of interest for me being `const Size _calendarPortraitDialogSizeM3 = Size(328.0, 512.0);`  
Is there any way to override this value without just copying the entirety of the source code for date_picker.dart and changing the value myself? I fear this would introduce maintenance concerns with trying to keep my copied version of the date_picker.dart code up to date with changes to the original source code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution I can think of is to use `Transform.scale`.

```
showDatePicker(
  context: context,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime(2010),
  lastDate: DateTime.now(),
  builder: (context, child) {
    /// Apply a transform to the date picker.
    /// You can calculate the value of [scale] based on device size, etc.
    return Transform.scale(
      scale: 1.33, /// 33% bigger
      child: child,
    );
  },
);
```