# How to remove gray background in showDatePicker() and showTimePicker()

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a function that asks the user for date and time. It look like this:

```java
Future<DateTime?> getDate(BuildContext context) async {
  DateTime? date = await showDatePicker(
    context: context,
    initialDate: DateTime.now(),
    firstDate: DateTime(1950),
    lastDate: DateTime(2100),
  );

  if (date == null) return null;

  TimeOfDay? time = await showTimePicker(
    context: context,
    initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
    initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
  );
  DateTime? dateAndTime = date.add(Duration(
    hours: time?.hour ?? 0,
    minutes: time?.minute ?? 0,
  ));

  return dateAndTime;
}
```

Both `showDatePicker()` and `showTimePicker()` have a gray background that you commonly see in `showDialog()`.

In `showDialog()`, I can add `barrierColor: Colors.transparent`, but `showDatePicker` and `showTimePicker()` don't have this property.

How can I remove this gray background?

Answer (score 0):

You override the `ThemeData` or use `builder` of `showTimePicker`

```dart
 showTimePicker(
      context: context,
      initialEntryMode: TimePickerEntryMode.input,
      initialTime: TimeOfDay.now(),
      builder: (context, child) {
        return Theme(
          data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
          /// use `colorScheme: ` for more
          // date picker dialogBackground color in simple case
          dialogBackgroundColor: Colors.amber,
            timePickerTheme: TimePickerTheme.of(context).copyWith(
          //background color of time picker              
            backgroundColor: Colors.yellow, 
            ),
          ),
          child: child!,
        );
      },
    );
```

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50321182/10157127) to customize a date picker.

Answer (score 0):

Modify surface color using the theme data's color scheme parameter.

```
Future<DateTime?> showDateTimePicker(BuildContext ctx) async {
DateTime? selectedDate = await showDatePicker(
  builder: (BuildContext context, Widget ?child) {
    var themeBloc = BlocProvider.of<ThemeBloc>(context);
    return Theme(
      data: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.grey,
        splashColor:  Theme.of(context).secondaryHeaderColor,
        textTheme: TextTheme(
          titleMedium: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
          labelLarge: TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
        ),
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.light(
             primary: Theme.of(context).primaryColorLight,
            onSecondary: themeBloc.state.themeMode == ThemeMode.dark.toString()
                ? Colors.white
                : Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            onPrimary: Colors.white,
            surface: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
            onSurface: themeBloc.state.themeMode == ThemeMode.dark.toString()
                ? Colors.white
                : Theme.of(context).primaryColorDark,
            secondary: Colors.white
        ),
        dialogBackgroundColor: Theme.of(context).scaffoldBackgroundColor,
      ),
      child: child ?? Text(""),
    );
  },
  context: ctx,
  initialDate: DateTime.now(),
  firstDate: DateTime.now(),
  lastDate: DateTime.now().add(const Duration(days: 60)),
);
return selectedDate;
```

}