# is there a way to change the display of date picker in flutter?

Tags: flutter, datepicker

(sorry I'm not good at English),

I'm trying to  change date picker's look when click a button without display the default layout.

I didn't found anything to change the display of it

like this : https://i.stack.imgur.com/kzqHA.png

Comment: do you want to change the layout of date picker , is that your question

Comment: yes , i want to choose for example the next day only by clicking a button and display it without the default layout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**solution 1**

you can use this plugin for **flutter_rounded_date_picker**

please go through the link

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_rounded_date_picker

**solution 2**

please go through this link , it's kind of similar question you are asked

[How to customize a date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50321182/17180860)