# Flutter - Change the font of the date picker in the SfCalender

Tags: flutter, fonts, sfcalendar

I'm creating a flutter app that uses the SfCalendar widget. I have set `showDatePickerButton: true`. I'm trying to change the font family of all the text is my app. I've set the default theme in the MaterialApp to use the new font. I've also wrapped the SfCalendar in an SfCalendarTheme widget like so.

```
child: SfCalendarTheme(
  data: SfCalendarThemeData(
    headerTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
    activeDatesTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
    viewHeaderDayTextStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.bodyMedium,
  ),
  child: SfCalendar(
    view: CalendarView.month,
    showDatePickerButton: true,
    // more code here ...
  ),
),
```

However, there are still a few spots in the date picker where I can't seem to alter the font. I included a screenshot for reference. I made the new font cursive to make it easier to see. I tried following [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73670661/how-to-change-font-in-flutter-date-picker) for updating the font of a stand alone date picker, with no success.

[image: SfCalendar with the new font family]

[image: SfCalendar date picker with some of the text using the original font family]

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and will affect downstream re-users of your code.