# How to change datepicker color in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-datetime-picker

```
builder: (context, child) {
                return Theme(
                  data: Theme.of(context).copyWith(
                    colorScheme: const ColorScheme.light(
                      primary: Colors.white,
                      onPrimary: Colors.black,
                    ),
                    textButtonTheme: TextButtonThemeData(
                      style: TextButton.styleFrom(
                        foregroundColor: Colors.black,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  child: child!,
                );
              },
```

[image]

This is my code. And I want to make the header white. But the button is not visible when the header is white. What should I do?

Comment: that would be primary which you set white for it.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to customize a date picker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50321182/how-to-customize-a-date-picker)

Comment: It's not working...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [today color is `colorScheme.primary`](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/20fa32e129bd9b01f60f6152467c6e534eeb5e0d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart#L948) which is white, and we can't see.

```dart
    final Color todayColor = colorScheme.primary;

   .....

        } else if (isToday) {
          // The current day gets a different text color and a circle stroke
          // border.
          dayColor = todayColor;
          decoration = BoxDecoration(
            border: Border.all(color: todayColor),
            shape: BoxShape.circle,
          );
        }
```

You can check the [calendar_date_picker.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/20fa32e129bd9b01f60f6152467c6e534eeb5e0d/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/calendar_date_picker.dart#L984-L991)

For now, I can think of creating a local file and customize the color, or changing picker color.